# Testing a login component with Jest

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I'm not great at testing, and new to Jest and Enzyme. I  have a Login component that consists of two TextInput components for username and password and a Button component. I am testing each component individually.

I would just like to test that a username and password was returned by onLogin.

Here is the component:

```
export const onLogin = (user, password) => {
  console.log('User', user, 'Password', password)
  return [user, password];
};

function Login() {
  const [user, setUser] = useState("");
  const [password, setPassword] = useState("");

  return (
    <LoginWrapper>
      <Branding brand={brand.brandName} />
      <FormWrapper onSubmit={(e) => { e.preventDefault(); onLogin(user, password) }}>
        <Stack>
          <TextInput
            className="username"
            type="text"
            label="Username"
            onChange={e => setUser(e.target.value)}
          />
        </Stack>
        <Stack>
          <TextInput
            className="password"
            type="password"
            label="Password"
            onChange={e => {setPassword(e.target.value); console.log('user', user)}}
          />
        </Stack>
        <Stack padding="0" align="right">
          <Button type="submit">Login</Button>
        </Stack>
      </FormWrapper>
    </LoginWrapper>
  );
}

export default Login;
```

My test:

```
describe("<Login />", () => {
  it("renders text input correctly", () => {
    const tree = renderer.create(<ThemeProvider theme={themes.default}><Login /></ThemeProvider>).toJSON();
    expect(tree).toMatchSnapshot();
  });

  it("calls onLogin when button clicked", () => {
    const onSubmitMock = jest.fn();

    const component = Enzyme.mount(
      <ThemeProvider theme={themes.default}><Login onSubmit={onSubmitMock} /></ThemeProvider>
    );

    component.find("input.username").simulate('change', { target: { value: 'myUser' } })
    component.find("input.password").simulate('change', { target: { value: 'myPassword' } })
    component.find("form").simulate("submit");

    console.log("onClickMock.mock", onSubmitMock.mock)
    expect(onSubmitMock).toBeCalled()
  });
});
```

Results:

> Expected mock function to have been called, but it was not called.

Comment: I suggest you to move the `onLogin` function into an other file like `login.utils.js`. The you can use `jest.mock('./login.utils')` in your test so the `import {onLogin} from './login.utils'` will give you a mocked function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your testing approach is correct except for:

1. In your test, you are mocking a callback function and passing it as a property `onSubmit` to your component. Then you need to call this function from your component when you submit the form.
2. Instead,  you are calling the `onLogin` function on your component that does not have any
   repercussion.

In order to fix this, declare the properties on your component function as a parameter, and call `props.onSubmit` on your form submit.

```
function Login(props) {
    const [user, setUser] = useState("");
    const [password, setPassword] = useState("");

    return (
        <LoginWrapper>
            <Branding brand={brand.brandName} />
            <FormWrapper onSubmit={(e) => { e.preventDefault(); props.onSubmit(user, password) }}>
                <Stack>
                    <TextInput
                        className="username"
                        type="text"
                        label="Username"
                        onChange={(e) => setUser(e.target.value)}
                    />
                </Stack>
                <Stack>
                    <TextInput
                        className="password"
                        type="password"
                        label="Password"
                        onChange={(e) => { setPassword(e.target.value) }}
                    />
                </Stack>
                <Stack padding="0" align="right">
                    <Button type="submit">Login</Button>
                </Stack>
            </FormWrapper>
        </LoginWrapper>
    );
}
```